# Will SSD drive make maven builds faster?

Tags: maven, solid-state-drive

[Good post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557934/would-a-ssd-vs-fast-hdd-drive-make-my-eclipse-run-compile-faster) says speed better with SSD drive for Eclipse work.

But my slow part is mostly for maven builds. I have project with 1600+ classes. It take 2-3 min for a clean build with maven. I wonder if SSD drive will make it faster? Because SSD drive is big improvement on reads, but smaller improvement on writes as I understand.

I wonder if anyone has experimented with this?

Comment: The majority of operations in Maven is reading (dependencies, pom file, jar files etc. from local repository) the minor is writing.

Comment: Except when you are building a project for the first time and Maven has to Download Teh Internets.

Comment: I have, and it's a really big improvement, even in writing. Do not hesitate :)

Comment: Darmont, thank you. How big was maven project when you tried? Would you say twice as fast, three times, ten times...?

Comment: Voted to close. This is too much a "yes or no" or "your mileage may vary" question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSD write speed is slower than read speed *but* you don't have dsk access latency to pay, so will nearly always be faster than HDD, especially for Maven builds which spit out lots of small files (ie very random access)

Read [this reasonable summary of the SSD vs HDD performance differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive#Comparison_of_SSD_with_hard_disk_drives) but I am confident that for *every Maven build* you will find it is access latency and not write throughput that affects your build speed.

TL;DR go for the SSD