# Ways to make maven build faster?

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, maven, build

I have a multi module java project. Maven takes almost around 40 secs to build it. I have tried maven with multi threaded builds too by specifying -T and -C args for no of threads and cores to be used. But I haven't seen any significant improvement in wall time of my builds.

I am using maven 3.2.3 and sometimes I need to build my project very frequently.

I know that clean goal take a lot of time but I can not omit it.

Suggestions please....

EDIT:

Note:  In my case clean is not taking much time. It finishes in 1 sec. install is taking rest of the time.

Comment: Have you tried building it *offline* using the `-o` option (assuming your dependencies don't change frequently)

Comment: No. I was unaware of -o option. Let me try it. Thanks.

Comment: @ TheLostMind Sorry. No improvements.

Comment: How many tests do you have? Why are you running very often? How many modules do you have?

Comment: I do skip tests. Around 30 modules

Comment: How long does the clean take?

Comment: Zeroturnaround published an interesting [article](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/your-maven-build-is-slow-speed-it-up/). Maybe you find some hints therein.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

#### ***Note: First thing is AFAIK, No other in built options available in maven apart from the all answers here.***

---

Running maven build with Multiple threads works for me to speed up the builds.
For example :

```
mvn clean install -T100
```

> where -T is for specifying how many threads you want based on your
>   hardware.

#### [Below are the variants from wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3)

> Maven 3.x has the capability to perform parallel builds.    The command
>   is as follows:
>
> - mvn -T 4 clean install   Builds with 4 threads
> - mvn -T 1C clean install  1 thread per cpu core
> - mvn -T 1.5C clean install 1.5 thread per cpu core

#### How Execution is evaluated([See Parallel builds in Maven 3](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3))?

[image]

Each node in the graph represents a module in a multi-module build, the "levels" simply indicate the distance to the first module in the internal reactor dependency graph. Maven calculates this graph based on declared inter-module dependencies for a multi-module build. Note that the parent maven project is also a dependency, which explains why there is a single node on top of most project graphs. Dependencies outside the reactor do not influence this graph.

***Finally if you want to skip test execution you can also use `-DskipTests` as well.***

***Caution :***  Some of your plugins may not be compatible for multithreaded builder, it may work. but it will give below warning message. you may need to see plugin documentation for multithreading support.

```
[WARNING] *****************************************************************                                                                                                                                 
[WARNING] * Your build is requesting parallel execution, but project      *                                                                                                                                 
[WARNING] * contains the following plugin(s) that have goals not marked   *                                                                                                                                 
[WARNING] * as @threadSafe to support parallel building.                  *                                                                                                                                 
[WARNING] * While this /may/ work fine, please look for plugin updates    *                                                                                                                                 
[WARNING] * and/or request plugins be made thread-safe.                   *                                                                                                                                 
[WARNING] * If reporting an issue, report it against the plugin in        *                                                                                                                                 
[WARNING] * question, not against maven-core                              *                                                                                                                                 
[WARNING] *****************************************************************                                                                                                                                 
[WARNING] The following plugins are not marked @threadSafe in test-project:                                                                                                                          
[WARNING] de.dentrassi.maven:rpm:0.9.2                                                                                                                                                                      
[WARNING] Enable debug to see more precisely which goals are not marked @threadSafe.                                                                                                                        
[WARNING] *****************************************************************
```

Comment: -DskipTests still compiles the tests.  If you want to skip compiling too, use -Dmaven.test.skip

Answer (score 70):

On my actual project :

1. `mvn clean install` [INFO] Total time: **01:05 h**
2. `mvn clean install -DskipTests` [INFO] Total time: **18:35 min**
3. `mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip -DskipTests` **[INFO] Total time: 10:58 min**
4. `mvn -T 1C clean install -Dmaven.test.skip -DskipTests` [INFO] Total time: **04:00 min**
5. We can also skip the javadoc to be generated as **Archmed commented** by adding **-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true** `mvn -T 1C clean install -Dmaven.test.skip -DskipTests -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true`
6. Don't use *** imports**, on IntelliJ, choose > Analyze > Run inspection by name > * imports , to find all * imports and correct it.
7. Remove all **unused imports** in your project > on Intellij > Analyze > Run inspection by name > unused imports
8. Remove all **unused code** (classes, variable, field, parameter, etc..), on Intellij : Analyze > run inspection by name > unused declaration.
9. Upgrade to **last JAVA VERSION**
10. I have found that the task **mvn clean**, is taking 2 minutes to clean the TARGET folder before building. I did create a new task called **quickclean**, and I am using it instead of clean, this way `mvn -T 1C quickclean install -Dmaven.test.skip -DskipTests` . This new task quickclean is only **renaming the build folder** from TARGET to TARGET-yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm(*what is VERY FAST*). So now, every time you make a new `mvn quickclean install...`, you have a folder with the time of the build. **The inconvenient**, it's that this may take **a lot of space on the hard disk**, so you have to clean all these directories sometimes. So for that I have created another task called: **trashclean**, to put all this folder to trash. I am running this tasks maybe on time per week. or month, depending on my work `mvn trashclean`.

Here is what you need to add to your pom.xml if you want to use this concept

```
<properties>
    <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    <trashdir>trash/target-${maven.build.timestamp}</trashdir>
</properties>

    <profile>
        <id>quickclean</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>rename_target</id>
                            <phase>pre-clean</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <tasks>
                                    <move todir="${trashdir}" failonerror="false">
                                        <fileset dir="target/"/>
                                    </move>
                                </tasks>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>trashclean</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>clean_trash</id>
                            <phase>clean</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <tasks>
                                    <delete dir="trash/" failonerror="false"/>
                                </tasks>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Comment: Why the difference between 2 and 3?

Comment: 2 still compiles the tests but doesn't run them, 3 doesn't even compile the tests. `-DskipTests` is redundant in 3 and can be left out, it will yield identical results.

Comment: I would also recommend adding `-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true` if you're compiling for local build. This will skip creating javadocs which is a huge help on my machine

Comment: using ```mvn -T 1C clean install -Dmaven.test.skip -DskipTests``` decreased my build time from 25 minutes to 3:53 minutes. Thanks!

Comment: On my project (~3000 lines of code, 42 seconds maven build time on local machine), no compile time difference has been seen when removing 'import *' and using `-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true`. Maybe my project is too small... Skipping the tests reduces the maven build time by about 10 seconds (but I want my project to be tested so will not disable the tests).

Answer (score 6):

You can optimize the build by using of some small-2 trick like

1. If you have written Junit Test and dont want to run test case every time you can use `-DskipTests=true`
2. Locally Install Nexus or Repositories
3. You can adjust memory configurations to optimum for eg: add this line to `mvn.bat` set `MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m`

For more information you can check [How to Speed Your Maven build](http://bosy.dailydev.org/2009/02/speed-up-your-maven-build-four-times.html)

Comment: Also, SSD greatly accelerates build's speed.

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091425/will-ssd-drive-make-maven-builds-faster

Comment: Thanks @ Vartlok , @Subodh. SSD is not pragmatic in my case. Its a office PC

Comment: @ShubhamChaurasia You are Welcome

Comment: @Vartlok: any benchmarks showing comparison of build speed on hdd vs ssd?

Comment: You can set the memory settings via env-var like this: `export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"`. No need to touch the `mvn.bat`

Comment: `Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=256m'`

Answer (score 6):

You can do a hacky way if you have some extra RAM as I do, and you don't need SSD, because it's sensitive for SSD to do a lot of read-writes. Even if you disable +a bit (MacOS - I don't remember if Win have similar issue). But

1. create RAM drive (number of ways depends on your OS) and mount it to /Users/Username/volatile folder
2. locate maven-module-builder-X.X.X.jar in MVN_HOME/lib
3. in JAR modify file org/apache/maven/model/pom-4.0.0.xml by modifying

`&lt;build>&lt;directory>/Users/Username/volatile/${project.groupId}/${project.artifactId}/${project.version}/target`

4. From now on all project compilations will be done in memory. And it's a difference even in comparison with SSD.

Yes, its hack and some maven plugins can stop working BTW.

Answer (score 5):

If using commandline you can check how many cores your machine has and use all of them, if you also want to skip your tests, you can add `-DskipTests`
For example, I have 8 core processor:

```
mvn -T 8C clean install -DskipTests
```

Comment: The -T xC is actually threads per core so in your case it is 8 * 8 = 64 threads. If you want to specify the exact number of threads spawned by maven process you should use the -T x option. Source: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3

Answer (score 5):

Apart from parallel run which many of the folks have already mentioned, try these maven options which would speed up build 
-XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1

Comment: For me, these solution slowed down the build 30% of the time

Answer (score 5):

You can try turbo-maven-plugin to help speed up your multi module Maven builds locally (I am one of the plugin authors)?

https://github.com/sparebank1utvikling/turbo-maven-plugin

It works by analyzing what modules actually have code changes, and build only those and the modules dependent on them. More info about how it works here:

https://medium.com/sparebank1-digital/speed-up-your-multi-module-maven-builds-with-turbo-maven-plugin-4be0eb2a2601

Comment: After adding this plugin, alle modules are still compiled every time.

Comment: The first time you build after adding the plugin, it will analyze the modules, so it will build as normal. The second time you build, you should see that it does not build anything at all, given you haven't done any changes? 

There is an example project in the repo, where you can see the plugin in action.

Comment: Ok, i found my error and got it working. But i have issues when switching to another branch, the compiler complains about missing symbols when i do not recompile it completly.

Answer (score 1):

### Low-Level speed using Ramdisk (Windows)

My additional trick is using a ramdisk

1. Create a Ramdisk of 2GB (in example *D:*)
2. Install IDE, Maven, JDK and the `.m2/repository` to that Ramdisk (`D:/m2/`).
3. Edit the Maven's `D:/maven/conf/settings.xml` to use that Ramdisked repo (`<localRepository>D:/m2</localRepository>`)
4. Put the project into the ramdisk.
5. Run the project having its temp-folder in the Ramdisk.

On my machine I turned

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14.954 s (Wall Clock)
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-02-17T13:07:51+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 55M/642M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Into

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.805 s (Wall Clock)
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-11-11T10:48:14Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Both results are high-end (`-DskipTests -T 12`)

Warning: Do not forget to persist the ramdisk before shutdown or your work is lost.

Look at this beast:
[image]

Comment: I do not think you need your IDE, JDK or Maven in the Ramdisk.. It would make more sense to put maven repo and the project itself in the ramdisk.

Comment: @KorayTugay Naturaly the project must be in that ramdisk too. I thought that is clear but I edited the answer to point that out. Also the `-Djava.io.tmpdir=D:/temp` is important.

Comment: How much difference does putting the IDE in ramdisk make? I would think very little, am I wrong? Did you experience a big improvement by having the IDE in ramdisk too?

Comment: @KorayTugay I have two minor reasons. The first reason is that I have one Ramdisk-Image per project. Its like an all-in-one-container-ramdisk having the JDK of the project running the exact same JDK as the IDE what gives better debugging compatibilities. As an example: one project is a SWT project where I prefer to use netbeans. In the other project I use eclipse. Then there is a IntelliJ project. The second reason is that if I upgrade the IDE but am not sure if all my plugins are compatible, instead of rollback manually the IDE update I have a ramdisk backup to restore to an stable version.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring boot with maven and you feel like dependencies are coming slow to your system, try following setting in pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath /> 
</parent>
```

I experienced that **version 2.7.0** downloads the dependencies faster than other versions.